# Google Maps and ROR 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the [Google Maps 'Hello World'](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#HelloWorld) to work in ROR 3.1 using the following code:

in **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize($("div#map_canvas").get(0));
  });

function initialize(element) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(element, myOptions);
  alert("test");
}
```

in my model view partial **app/views/rides/_ride.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</li>
```

I have this in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag :application,  
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" %>
```

I'm new to ROR so any help with what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.  It seems like the javascript is being run (the alert message appears) but the map never shows up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your view

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
```

In your Javascript

```
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }
```

In your CSS

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
```

And include this in your layout/application

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly while using `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` that tag helper should automatically include the application.js (if it is present) at the end after it includes the other default js files.

The map isn't loading because the google map js file isnt included properly.
The `javascript_include_tag` helper takes path to the javascript files, both relative and absolute. In your case it take the absolute path just with the parameters, it does not send the parameters like sensor=false. That is why you are getting the alert at the end of the code but the map isn't getting generated. If you check the HTML of the page where this is done then you will see that the js file that would be included is

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which is wrong.
Using the below line you could include it in a right way, as in the parameters would get passed correctly.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type=text/javascript"> </script>
```

So use the HTML script tags to include the Google Map javascript.

jQuery methods for DOM manipulation etc. mostly return a jQuery object that isnt a HTML DOM element. The Google Map initialization for showing the map requires a DOM element that can be accessed by `document.getElementById(id);` (I think there might be a method that jQuery provides to convert a jQuery object to a DOM element, look it up.). Hope this helps, I could have posted a jsFiddle with the working code but decided to write all this up as the problem is also related to Rails. Let me know if you require further help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  By passing `$("div#map_canvas").get(0)` to my `initialize()` function I think I am now passing a HTML DOM element rather than the jQuery object.  However I don't understand what you say is wrong with my javascript_include_tag.  Also,despite what you and the documentation says, if I remove `application` the generated HTML does not include that link.  The link to googleapis appears to work fine.  Any more thoughts?

Comment: Perfect, jQuery get is what you need there. When you pass an absolute path to the javascript_include_tag helper it takes that as the src attribute to the js file. However what you need there is a way to pass the params to the request that is made to include the javascript file. From the post above if you try both the things mentioned you would see that the generated HTML would differ.

Comment: The helper would add a .js to the path which is passed(a .js after the URL the parameters passed along with the URL). If you check the HTML generated, it would show that thats not what you want.

Comment: I don't get the .js extension you notice (I'm using Rails 3.1) However, I think I solved my problem by changing the CSS style for the height/width which was being set to 0px.  I don't know why the 100% style wasn't working.  I switched to blueprint CSS and set the height width to exact px values.

Comment: hmm.. strange. well i tried this on a Rails 2 app and saw that the generated HTML to include the script was wrong. Not sure, probably in Rails 3 the helpers treat the params properly.